# p5.js Loading JSON only once?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

**Problem description**

Loading data using loadJSON() with callback keeps on loading the input data file over and over again. The number of items in containers keep growing and the browser slows down etc until out-of-memory.

**Expected result**

Stop loading data using loadJSON() once the input data has been read completely.

**Example Contents in the FILELIST.json**

The data contains an array of just 14 JSON entries, for example (now only using the BYTES as ellipse size)

```
{"BYTES":"97488","MONTH":"sep","DAY":"01","YEAR":"2018","PATH":"./addons/p5.dom.js"},
```

Each of these are plotted as ellipse after asynchronous loading.

```
var framerate = 2;
var containers = [];
var canvas_x = 700
var canvas_y = 500
var container_largest = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(canvas_x,canvas_y);
  setInterval(getData,1000);
}

function getData() {
  loadJSON("../FILELIST.json", gotData);
}

function gotData(data) {
  spaceData = data;
  console.log(data);
  // Handle new data
  for (var i = 0; i < spaceData.length; i++) {
      bytes = spaceData[i].BYTES;
      if (bytes > 0) {
        containers.push(new Container(bytes));
      }
      if (bytes > container_largest) {
        container_largest = bytes;
      }
    }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  frameRate(framerate)

  // Run all containers
  for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    containers[i].run(containers);
  }
}

function Container(size) {
    this.size = size;
    //console.log(size);
}

Container.prototype.run  = function(containers) {
  this.render();
}

Container.prototype.render = function() {
  fill(255);
  rel_size = int(this.size/container_largest);
  rel_size = int(canvas_x / (rel_size*containers.length));
  ellipse(random(canvas_x) ,random(canvas_y), rel_size, rel_size);
}
```

Comment: `setInterval(getData, 1000);` means you're calling `getData` and therefore `loadJSON` once every second.

Comment: Thank you this explains the continuous loading problem.